# Selenium Indexing a table to search multiple datapoints with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium, I would like to search multiple individual data points and grab the information from each search separately. I need it so that it just continuously runs until it has went through all of the datapoints. I imagine that it will be some sort of index mixed with a loop, but I am unsure even where to begin.

[Data Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmEDB.png)

```
###this information is what needs to come from the table and be searched I feel this is where the loop will begin 
fromcity.send_keys(city)
fromstate.send_keys(fromstate)
tocity.send_keys(tocity)
tostate.send_keys(tostate)

searchbttn.click()

###here the web scraper grabs the needed information, I also need to figure out how to insert this information into the table in the correct spot.
miles1=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]')
miles2=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]')

miles1=oneweekrate.text
miles2=twoweeksrate.text
```

Comment: Hi perhaps, select each row, then iterate over the cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can find good links like:
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handle-dynamic-webtables-in-selenium-webdriver/

This is my examle, I have a different type of elements that I need to click.
Principe of iteration trough the table is same. This is my code.

WebElement timerTable = DP.GetTimerTable();

int rowCount = timerTable.findElements(By.xpath("//tr")).size();

```
    for(int i =2;i<=rowCount;i++)
    {

        String timer = timerTable.findElement(By.xpath("//tr["+i+"]/td[1]/p")).getText().trim();
        log.info("This is a role name for submission:"+timer);
        if (timer.contains(timerName))
        {
            ScroolDown(driver, 500);
            sleep(200);
            WebElement cellToClick = timerTable.findElement(By.xpath("//tr["+i+"]/td[1]/p"));
            cellToClick.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='javascript']")).click();
            break;  
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT) This what I have came up with an works.

This is what I have so far.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

ocity=(row["Origin              City"])
ostate=(row["Origin State"])
dcity=(row["Destination                               City"])
dstate=(row["Destination State"])
fromcity=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_RateSearchControl_OriginLocation_textCity"]')
fromstate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_RateSearchControl_OriginLocation_textState"]')
tocity=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_RateSearchControl_DestinationLocation_textCity"]')
tostate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_RateSearchControl_DestinationLocation_textState"]')
searchbttn=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_RateSearchControl_buttonFindRates"]')
fromcity.clear()
fromstate.clear()
tocity.clear()
tostate.clear()
fromcity.send_keys(ocity)
fromstate.send_keys(ostate)
tocity.send_keys(dcity)
tostate.send_keys(dstate)
searchbttn.click()
oneweekrate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]')
twoweeksrate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]')
onemonthrate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]')
ninetydaysrate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]')
oneyearrate=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]')
oneweekratetext=oneweekrate.text
twoweeksratetext=twoweeksrate.text
onemonthratetext=onemonthrate.text
ninetydaysratetext=ninetydaysrate.text
oneyearratetext=oneyearrate.text
df.at[index, "oneweekrate"]=oneweekratetext
df.at[index, "twoweeksrate"]=twoweeksratetext
df.at[index, "onemonthrate"]=onemonthratetext
df.at[index, "ninetydaysrate"]=ninetydaysratetext
df.at[index, "oneyearratetext"]=oneyearratetext
```